# $result = parent::save($key, $urlVar); not always saving to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, joomla, form-submit

I have a form in joomla 2.5 which allows for donations. On submit, the form does the following..

1. External email validation, if good than proceeds
2. Processes paypment via authorize.net, 
   if successful, the following both should run
3. Saves the form values in a database
4. Sends various emails to user and to me.

My question is in regards to #3. The save triggers through the following line:

```
$result = parent::save($key, $urlVar);
```

Out of the last 50 submits, 3 did not save in the database even though they were charged via authorize.net and emails were sent to the user and me. What would be the best way to test/break down what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to troubleshoot is to write the variables before sending and after receiving from authorize.net to a text file. When you analyse the log data which is not entered to the database you will exactly come to know why that happened. In my Paypal plugin I follow this code for writing to a text file

```
function log_ipn_results($success) {
        if ($this->ipn_log) {
            $text   = '[' . date('m/d/Y g:i A') . '] PAYPAL RESPONSE - ';
            if ($success)
                $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
            else $text .= "FAIL!\n";
            $text   .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
            foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
                $text .= "$key=$value, ";
            }
            $text   .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n " . $this->ipn_response;
            $fp     = fopen($this->ipn_log_file, 'a');//Your log file path
            fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");
            fclose($fp);  // close file
        } else {
            // @todo does not log ipn file
        }
    }
```

Similar way you can store response from authorise.net server, and later you can analyse it.

Comment: thank you for responding. A little more explanation.. A separate array is made and sent to Authorize.net for processing. Authorize sends a response.. either "success" or "fail". The save to database + email code only runs if the response is "success" `if ($payment == 'success')`. So the variables are going to authorize.net for sure. The problem seems to be in the `$result = parent::save($key, $urlVar);` line, if instead I had access to the actual insert into query than I could test if rows changed. Instead, that function points to joomla core files.